# Why does "in" behave differently for lists and tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code

```py
for item in ('sin', 'cos', 'sinc', 'sin^2'):
    print(item not in ('sin^2'))
```

produces the result

```
False
True
True
False
```

but

```py
for item in ('sin', 'cos', 'sinc', 'sin^2'):
    print(item not in ['sin^2'])
```

produces the result

```
True
True
True
False
```

Why?

Comment: You don't have a tuple in the first one. You just have a string.

Comment: `('sin^2')` is not a tuple, that is a string. The *comma* makes the tuple, not the parentheses. Note, `my_tuple = 1,2` is a valid tuple, so is `my_tuple = 3,` and `my_tuple = (3,)`, whereas `my_tuple = (3)` is an `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is being treated as a parenthesized string rather than a tuple. So it ends up being a substring match. To define it as a single-element tuple, there must be a trailing comma:

```
print(item not in ('sin^2',))
```

This is described here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax